# Why does SumIf returns 0 with Double and returns true with integer in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, sumifs

The below is a simple `SumIf` calculation where I want to `sumif >=` the variable `k` that is declared as a `Double`.

This, however returns 0. If I change `k` for any integer, 3, 4 etc, it returns the `true` value. But if I change `k` for `4.23983` it returns `0`.

I already tried to declare another `Double` variable (lets say `a`) and put `a = sumif(...)`. But that gives me `0` as well. I also tried `"">="& k &"""` but that doesn't work either (found that on Google).

```
Worksheets("ES").Cells(j + 10, 6).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Worksheets("help").Range("A1:A4273"), ">=" & k, Worksheets("help").Range("A1:A4273"))
```

Comment: have you tried sumifs?

Comment: Improved title, added related tags and improved formatting for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

Last edit. Based on comments, circumstances require conversion from European format to US for calculations. Please refer to this post for bulk of code used:
[VBA - Evaluate Conditions as String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397050/vba-evaluate-conditions-as-string)

Here's a function that can be added to a module and used freely in the worksheet:

```
    Function EuroSumIf(ByVal CellRange As Range, ByVal Condition As String, ByVal CompareVal As Double) As Double
        Dim cond As String

        Dim vx As MSScriptControl.ScriptControl
        Set vx = New MSScriptControl.ScriptControl
        Dim sum As Double

        For Each cell In CellRange.Cells
            a = cell.Value
            b = CompareVal
            If InStr(1, a, ".", vbTextCompare) > -1 Then
                a = Replace(a, ".", "")
            End If
            If InStr(1, a, ",", vbTextCompare) > -1 Then
                a = Replace(a, ",", ".")
            End If
            cond = "(a" & Condition & "b)"
            'MsgBox (cond & vbLf & a & Condition & b)
            With vx
                .Language = "VBScript"
                .AddCode "function stub(a,b): stub=" & cond & ": end function"
                If .Run("stub", a, b) Then
                    sum = sum + a
                End If
            End With
        Next
        EuroSumIf = sum
    End Function
```

Use as follows:

```
    =EuroSumIf(A1:A3,">",0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately that too returns 0 for me. I'm situated in Sweden and the values in A:A are all Doubles with commas instead of dots i.e. 4,34349 etc. Perhaps this might be a problem?

Comment: That might make it bit difficult... Try adding Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "General" before you set your value. I'm looking into reverting the format back to European.

Comment: Basic question, but is your 'k' value in the same format as the data in your sheet?

Comment: When I print k in a cell I get values such as 3,565237483. Samples of my data:1,232919697
0,751413045
1,052537219
0,988095736
1,94284242
2,503066757

Comment: Okay, I don't know any better, but my last suggestion is kind of a hack. You might need to drop the SumIf function and go with a good 'ol For statement and iterate through the range(s) to compare and sum. There must be an issue with the European format and the way the SumIf function parses the string into a double.

Comment: Updated my answer, the function provided doesn't convert the value back into European format however... Doing so might require the target value cell to be formatted to accept the European format as the reference cells are.